# Django web app not redirecting and not posting

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-2.0

I an not sure where is the problem as I press submit button, it went through with no error shown. It was supposed to update the database with the data filled in form then redirect them back to 'search' page (option.html).

models.py:

```
OptionChoice = (
    ('A','A'),
    ('B','B'),
    ('C','C'),
    )

class OptionPlan(models.Model):
    option = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=OptionChoice, default="DEFAULT", blank=True)
    ...
    updated = models.DateField(max_length=20, null=True)
    updatedBy = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
```

urls.py:

```
app_name = 'Benefits'

urlpatterns = [
    path('simple_upload', views.simple_upload, name='simple_upload'),
    #path('search', views.search, name='search'),
    path('search/', FilterView.as_view(filterset_class=BenefitsFilter, template_name='Benefits/option.html'), name='search'),
    path('OptionUpdate/<int:id>', views.OptionUpdate.as_view(), name='OptionUpdate')
    ]
```

views.py:

```
def search(request):
    option = OptionPlan.objects.get_queryset()
    option_filter = BenefitsFilter(request.GET, queryset=option)

    return render(request, 'Benefits/option.html', {'filter':option_filter})

class OptionUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = OptionPlan

    fields =[
        'option',
        ...
        'cb_updatedBy',
        'cb_updated',
        ]

    template_name = 'Benefits/OptionUpdate.html'
    slug_field = 'id'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'id'

    def form_valid(self, request, obj, form, change):
        OptionPlan = form.save(commit=False)
        if OptionPlan.option and 'option' in form.changed_data:
            OptionPlan.updatedBy = str(self.request.user)
            OptionPlan.updated = timezone.localtime(timezone.now())
        OptionPlan.save()
        return redirect('Benefits:search')
```

optionUpdate.html:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}

    <div style="margin-left:100px;margin-right:100px;">
        <form method="POST">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <h2 class="alert alert-primary">...</h2>

                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-4" style="font-size:30px;">
                            {{ form.option|as_crispy_field }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    ...

                <div class="col">
                    <h2 class="alert alert-success">...</h2>
                      ...
                    <div class="col" style="font-size:30px;">
                        {{ form.cb_remarks|as_crispy_field }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">2020 Option Form Update</button>
            </div>
        </form>    
     </div>
{% else %}
```

Thank you so much for helping!

Edit:

[image]

Comment: could you provide more info on what happens when you click submit? What's the response? Do you use some debugger?

Comment: Hi ladorm, please see above screenshot. When I click submit, it supposed to update the database and redirect the user to option.html. And I am not using any debugger. Thank you!

Comment: Are there any many-to-many fields in the OptionPlan model?  Might try adding OptionPlan.save_m2m() after OptionPlan.save() 
see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

Comment: There is no foreign key/ one-many or many-to-many.

Comment: It shows me no errors when I click submit. but it just refused to update the database and redirect to where it should be!

Comment: did you try the the save_m2m() method?

Comment: Yes, there was no difference.

Comment: Seems like you're not getting to form_valid, so there must be something wrong with the form. Maybe add a print statement to form_invalid() or add the form errors to the template? That should show you what your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Django are you using?  A cursory look at generic [UpdateView](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/)* from Django v1.3 through v2.2 use this same post method:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Handle POST requests: instantiate a form instance with the passed
    POST variables and then check if it's valid.
    """
    form = self.get_form()
    if form.is_valid(): <--- you passed here so your form is valid
        return self.form_valid(form) <-- you overwrote this method (problem area)
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form)
```

*get familiar with that website if you are using class based views, its a life saver.

I am not sure how your form_valid method is being called with four variables: request, obj, form, change when it only expects one variable.

I typically split this logic apart and would make a separate form:

```
forms.py

class OptionPlanUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = OptionPlan
        fields = [
            'option',
            'cb_updatedBy',
             ...
            'cb_updated',
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        option_plan = super().save(commit=False)
        if 'option' in self.changed_data:
            option_plan.updatedBy = str(self.user)
            option_plan.updated = timezone.localtime(timezone.now())
        option_plan.save()
        return option_plan
```

Since we have a form we have to update our view to handle the form.  We pass the user to the form through the get_form_kwargs method.

```
class OptionUpdate(UpdateView):
    form_class = OptionPlanUpdateForm
    model = OptionPlan
    slug_field = 'id'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'id'
    template_name = 'Benefits/OptionUpdate.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('Benefits:search')

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs
```

***To test for errors in your form you can do the following:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.form_class(self.request.POST)
    print(form.errors)
    return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: You are a life saver!! I have been stuck here for daysssss! Using the errors test. I was able to pin point the problem. It was the cb_updated and cb_updatedBy are required. I have to add blank=True. 
Moreover, I have updated my app using the above code. It works like a charm! Thank you so much!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

If I were to assume, the form is throwing some type of error that you aren't printing nor handling. Try checking if any form errors exists to begin with.

Comment: I am new to django. Would you please show me how I can check if there is any errors in the form? Thank you!